# Word or idiom to describe someone who always tries to inflate his skills/properties/experiences when talking with others?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, slang, idiom-requests

Is there a word or idiom to describe someone who is always trying to create a good impression when talking about himself? Someone who is always trying to show that he is better than others even if he is not.

For example, when you talk to someone about a trip to an amazing place and then the person you are chatting with says that he went on a better trip than yours, that you bought a great car but this person's is better... and so on.

Comment: Headline and body of this question are somewhat at odds. Having had a more thrilling vacation or having a fancier car are neither of them advantages in *skill.*

Comment: You're talking about my neighbor, of course.

Comment: The person habitually engages in ***one-upmanship***.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**Blowhard**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blowhard) : someone who always brags or boasts about himself.

> He is also a braggart, bragger, line-shooter, vaunter, etc.

*Blowhard is an informal word describing someone who can't stop talking about themselves or their accomplishments, real or imagined.*

> From **ODO**:
>
> blowhard: A person who blusters and boasts in an unpleasant way.

*My pick* for an instance of boastful talk exhibiting self-importance
: **[Crowing](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/crowing)**

**Idioms:**

-[all bark and no bite](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/all_bark_and_no_bite)

-[all hat and no cattle](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/all_hat_and_no_cattle)

-etc.

Comment: "All bark and no bite" doesn't mean someone who brags as much as someone who intimidates people but doesn't act on the intimidation.

Comment: "All hat and no cattle," similarly, implies a failure to have the goods to back the bravado; and OP said nothing about the offender's *not having had* the better trip or car.

Answer (score 10):

That person could be called a *"[braggart](https://www.google.com/#q=braggart)"*

From the Google Dictionary:

> brag·gart
>
> /ˈbraɡərt/
>
> noun: braggart; plural noun: braggarts
>
> a person who boasts about achievements or possessions.

Answer (score 5):

The standard colloquial term for such behaviour is

> [**one-upmanship**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/one-upmanship) *- the technique or practice of gaining an advantage or feeling of superiority over another person*

Answer (score 4):

I suggest **poseur**.

a person who pretends to be what he or she is not :  an affected or insincere person

Merriam Webster

Comment: Isn't it really subjective whether or not their car or vacation is better than yours?  I think a poseur is more like someone who lies about what they've done or what they have.

Answer (score 4):

According to Urban Dictionary, a common slang word for such a person is a [topper](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=topper); they always have to "top" what someone else says.

Answer (score 2):

The person could be said to be self-aggrandizing.

TheFreeDictionary:

> **self-ag·gran·dize·ment**
>
> /sĕlf′ə-grăn′dĭz-mənt/
>
> *n.* The act or practice of enhancing or exaggerating one's own importance, power, or reputation.
>
> **self′-ag·gran′diz′ing** /-ə-grăn′dī′zĭng/ *adj.*

Answer (score 0):

A slang expression is: *to get [cocky](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cocky)*: (from TFD)

> - Overly self-assertive or self-confident, 
>     arrogant, conceited.
>
>   - A very cocky young man.
>   - I'm just listing the nominees, so not a great time to get cocky.